# Setting thread affinity before creating OpenCL context leads to Segfault

Tags: c++, pthreads, opencl, intel

I'm setting the affinity of the main thread to core 0 but the OpenCl context creation ends with a segfault. (I joined a code snippet to reproduce the problem, I removed vector size check to keep it concise as possible).

If I define more than one core in my cpuset everything works fine.

I have gut feeling about what could be wrong. But I would prefer a concrete explanation.

And then an error could be nicer than a raw segfault.

Open CL info:

- **Device Version** Intel OpenCL 1.2 (Build 475)
- **Driver Version** 1.2.0.475

```cpp
#include <vector>

#include <CL/cl.hpp>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Set affinity to core 0
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(0, &cpuset);
    pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);

    // Retrieve first platform
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    cl::Platform platform = platforms[0];

    // Retrieve first CPU device
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, &devices);
    cl::Device device = devices[0];

    // Create context
    cl::Context ctx(device);

    return 0;
}
```

*Edit: add OpenCL version*

Comment: CL_CPU_DEVICE_CPU picks CPU as a whole to compute, but host can't use some cores because of affinity? Try device fission feature of opencl to break device into cores and use same core(that host is set with affinity) as "compute subdevice" too. Then set the affinity.

Comment: "snippet to reproduce the problem" - doesn't really help unless you say which OpenCL implementation you're using. "error could be nicer than a raw segfault" - yes, which is why you should check that "devices" vector is not empty, before trying to use devices[0].

Comment: Sorry for this missing information. My real code has of course vector size checks. The segfault seems to occur during `clcreatecontext `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your example with two Intel OpenCL SDKs, but didn't have your exact version at hand. Both ran without errors, so: **cannot reproduce**.

This one seems a bit older than yours (by the build number):

```
CL_DEVICE_VERSION:          OpenCL 1.2 (Build 43)
CL_DRIVER_VERSION:          1.2.0.43
CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION: OpenCL C 1.2
```

The second one is, I think, still the most recent Intel CPU driver:

```
CL_DEVICE_VERSION:          OpenCL 2.1 (Build 0)
CL_DRIVER_VERSION:          18.1.0.0920
CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION: OpenCL C 2.0
```

I used GCC 7.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.4.

To my experience **it is not a problem to set affinity with the Intel OpenCL Runtime for CPUs**.

I used it together with MPI on supercomputers, where you would have multiple, e.g. 4, MPI processes per compute node and then have the runtime set each **process'** CPU mask to a disjunct subset of the available cores. The Intel OpenCL Runtime (using Intel Threading Building Blocks under the hood) inside each process would then spawn one thread per assigned core, i.e. adhere to the host process' CPU mask as expected. Maybe the result is different if you set the first thread's affinity, and also depends on where in the program you set (relative to where the OpenCL runtime spawns it's threads).

As you seem to already have run your code in a debugger and narrowed things down to `clcreatecontext`. **I'd suggest you try using a newer OpenCL driver.**